# set image view in table layout dynamically in android

Tags: android, imageview, android-tablelayout, tablerow

in my application i'm setting an imageview textview dynamically in table row of table layout.
but i couldn't set imageview.i tried it.its olny displaying textview not imageview. how can i set imageview.
please help me.
below is the code-

```
 Bitmap b=ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile((file.getPath()+".jpeg")), 50,50);

            im=new ImageView(this);
            im.setImageBitmap(b);
            im.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,50));


            nameoffile=new TextView(this);
            nameoffile.setText(myfile);
            nameoffile.setWidth(200);

            sizeoffile=new TextView(this);
            sizeoffile.setText(size+"KB");
            sizeoffile.setWidth(100);

            tr=new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(im);
            tr.addView(nameoffile);
            tr.addView(sizeoffile);
            tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
im.setImageResource(b);
```

instead of

```
im.setImageBitmap(b);
```